# QTP regular expression

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I have problem with regular expression in QTP, can't understand why this pattern doesn't work:

```
Dim objRegExp
Set objRegExp = New RegExp
                objRegExp.Pattern = Replace(Replace(Replace("Millennium [AUT]", "\", "\\"), "(", "\("), ")", "\)")
                objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
If objRegExp.Execute("Millennium [AUT]").Count < 1 Then
    Set objRegExp = Nothing
End If
```

Method Count return 0 value, could someone help, pls.

Answer (score 1):

Your .Replace chain does not change the pattern "Millennium [AUT]" which searchs for "Millennium" follwed by " ", followd by one letter out of "A", "U", or "T". Your input "Millennium [AUT]" has a "[" where the pattern expects "A", "U", or "T".

So please follow the general rule when asking for solutuions of regexp problems: Give at least one sample input and its expected outcome.

Perhaps you meant:

```
>> set r = New RegExp
>> r.Pattern = "Millennium \[AUT\]"
>> set mts = r.Execute("Millennium [AUT]")
>> WScript.Echo mts.Count
>>
1
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this site to verify my REGEX:

http://regexpal.com/

Good Luck!

Comment: a VBScripter will need lots of luck, if she uses a "Javascript regex tester" to verify VBScript RegExps.